# Can't Center Text Next to Input Box

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I can't get the text to be next to the search bar. I tried using padding for the input box but instead of it moving I end up making the box itself wider or increase in height. I also tried moving the search text using padding and margin but I still can't get the text to move the way I want it. I looked at some similar questions posted on Stack as well but I still was not able to fix my page. I want the "Search" text and the input box next to each other, similar to how you would see it on a form. Is padding and margin not the correct things to use to move text and search bar? Here is my code and an image of what my page currently looks like.

[image]

HTML

```
<p id="textnexttosearchbar">Search</p>
<input type="text" id="searchbar">
```

CSS

```
/*Seach bar at top*/
#searchbar{
    margin-left: 200px;
}

/*Text next to search bar at top*/
#textnexttosearchbar{
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: [`<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) tags and [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) tags are both block-level elements which means that they display on a new line underneath their preceding element. If you want them to be side by side, you can make your `<p>` tag `display: inline-block;` or if your layout is more complicated you could reach for [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your elements' display properties are `block` by default. Change to `inline-block` and you'll be all set.

```css
/*Seach bar at top*/
#searchbar{
    margin-left: 200px;
}

/*Text next to search bar at top*/
#textnexttosearchbar{
    margin-left:20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p id="textnexttosearchbar">Search</p>
<input type="text" id="searchbar">
```

Comment: I can't accept the answer right away, it won't let me, I will in a couple of minutes. I spent so long trying to figure this out, your answer finally fixed my problem, thanks a ton! @DCR